# Why regex r"</.?>" does not pick up "</\\\\>"?

Tags: python, regex

No match is found. Thanks!

```
import re

re_tag = re.compile(r"</.?>")
text = r"</\\\\>"
match = re_tag.search(text)
print(match)
```

Comment: If you are going to use regex to parse XML or HTML, do not. Use a proper parser for markup languages.

Comment: Are you confusing `?` with `*`, perhaps? `r'</.*>'` would match, among other things, arbitrary closing tags. (Or perhaps `*?`, which would perform a non-greedy match that would avoid false positives.)

Comment: Yes, I'm parsing HTML manually. The reason is that my main purpose is to extract the text. I tried BeautifulSoup, which unfortunately does not preserve the page layout. I have to manually add line breaks.

Comment: Because in raw syntax, I believe `r"\\\\"` is 4 backslashes at the source parse level. Where the regex engine will look for 2 backslashes, one for each \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string `text` contains 4 literal backslashes. Your regular expression only allows a single optional character between `/` and `>`. It *will* match the 4-character string created by `r"</\>"` or `"</\\>"`, for example.

Comment: Yes, it should have been r"</.*?>".

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your expression to something like this (Absolutely I don't know what do you want to check by your regular expression exactly):

```
re_tag = re.compile(r"</.{0,4}>")
```

For just none to 4 any character

Or like this:

```
re_tag = re.compile(r"<.*>")
```

If you want to get any length of anything

Comment: Yes, this helps. Thank you!